# c# XML from descendants

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-phone-7

I am coding for WP7. I am expecting this code below to read the XML below:

```
_xml = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
                results.Items.Clear();
                foreach (XElement value in _xml
                    .Descendants("ResourceSets").Descendants("ResourceSet")
                    .Descendants("Resources").Descendants("Location"))
                {
                    Results _item = new Results();
                    _item.Place = value.Element("Name").Value;
                    _item.Lat = value.Element("Point").Element("Latitude").Value;
                    _item.Long = value.Element("Point").Element("Longitude").Value;

                    results.Items.Add(_item);
                }
```

But the foreach loop wont read it and place it in the _items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
  <Copyright>Copyright © 2011 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.</Copyright> 
  <BrandLogoUri>http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png</BrandLogoUri> 
  <StatusCode>200</StatusCode> 
  <StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription> 
  <AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode> 
  <TraceId>703e7f1427dd425185ded546ba8a0d2c|LTSM001154|02.00.126.3000|LTSMSNVM002008, LTSMSNVM001854, LTSMSNVM001853</TraceId> 
 <ResourceSets>
 <ResourceSet>
  <EstimatedTotal>4</EstimatedTotal> 
 <Resources>
 <Location>
  <Name>Ashford, Kent, United Kingdom</Name> 
 <Point>
  <Latitude>51.146636679768562</Latitude> 
  <Longitude>0.87603025138378143</Longitude> 
  </Point>
 <BoundingBox>
  <SouthLatitude>51.076602190732956</SouthLatitude> 
  <WestLongitude>0.72853825986385345</WestLongitude> 
  <NorthLatitude>51.21656522154808</NorthLatitude> 
  <EastLongitude>1.0235222429037094</EastLongitude> 
  </BoundingBox>
  <EntityType>PopulatedPlace</EntityType> 
 <Address>
  <AdminDistrict>England</AdminDistrict> 
  <AdminDistrict2>Kent</AdminDistrict2> 
  <CountryRegion>United Kingdom</CountryRegion> 
  <FormattedAddress>Ashford, Kent, United Kingdom</FormattedAddress> 
  <Locality>Ashford</Locality> 
  </Address>
  <Confidence>High</Confidence> 
  </Location>
  </Resources>
  </ResourceSet>
  </ResourceSets>
  </Response>
```

Comment: Have you considered XML serialization instead of reading manually? The XML appears to be simple enough that it should be describable (is that a word?) with simple classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the namespace on each of your element names. Try this:

```
XNamespace xns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1";
_xml = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
results.Items.Clear();
foreach (XElement value in _xml
    .Descendants(xns + "ResourceSets").Descendants(xns + "ResourceSet")
    .Descendants(xns + "Resources").Descendants(xns + "Location"))
{
    Results _item = new Results();
    _item.Place = value.Element(xns + "Name").Value;
    _item.Lat = value.Element(xns + "Point").Element(xns + "Latitude").Value;
    _item.Long = value.Element(xns + "Point").Element(xns + "Longitude").Value;
    results.Items.Add(_item);
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. It definitely had me scratching my head the first time I encountered it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you're using Descendants?

You could just do:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(YourXMLPath);
XmlNode locationNode = doc["ResourceSets"]["ResourceSet"]["Resources"]["Location"];
foreach(XmlElement value in locationNode.Children)
{
    Results _item = new Results();
                    _item.Place = value.Element("Name").Value;
                    _item.Lat = value.Element("Point").Element("Latitude").Value;
                    _item.Long = value.Element("Point").Element("Longitude").Value;

                    results.Items.Add(_item);

}
```

I don't have VS right now, but that should be close to it.
Of course a good behavior would be to check if nodes are null before getting the next one.

Comment: Sorry, this isnt possible, as I failed to mention im on WP7 which does not have XmlDocument class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ObservableCollection<Results> result = new ObservableCollection<Results>();

XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result.ToString());

var data = from c in xmldoc.Descendants("ResourceSets").Descendants("ResourceSet").Descendants("Resources").Descendants("Location")
    select new Results{
    Place = c.Element("Name").Value;
    Lat = c.Element("Point").Element("Latitude").Value;
    Long = c.Element("Point").Element("Longitude").Value;
    };
    foreach (Results obj in data) 
    {
        result.Add(obj);
    }
```

Have not tried, but this is how I do it.